# Firefox entension, alert

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I made an extension for chrome and now I'm trying to do the same for Firefox. I decide to use if it is possible the same way as for Chrome, i.e. use manifest.json and not use xul etc. I began from the simple extension which has an icon and after user click on it, shows alert. So, I believed, code should be as follow.

**manifest.json:**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Panels Demo",
  "version": "1.0",
  "applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "panels@mozilla.org"
    }
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Sidebar panels"
  }
}
```

and **background.js:**

```
'use strict';

/*global chrome:false */

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    alert("click");
});
```

But after clicking on icon alert is not shown. Why is it so?

Comment: have you read this - [Firefox WebExtensions Chrome incompatibilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities) - nevermind, if that's the whole code, it doesn't use anything incompatible

Comment: I asked the webext people on stackoveflow, hopefully they can help out. If you would like to join that channel here is the link: `irc://moznet/webextensions`. If you don't have a IRC client here is a mibbit, an html5 client, that will connect you to this room https://client00.chat.mibbit.com/?url=irc%3A%2F%2Firc.mozilla.org%2F%23webextensions

Answer (score 0):

It’s a [bug in the implementation](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1203394).  Hopefully we’ll get it fixed, but it isn’t the highest priority bug on our plate, so I’m not sure when that will happen.  If you wanted to try fixing it, I’m sure we would appreciate the help (and most of the code is written in JavaScript, so it’s not as crazy a proposal as it sounds)!